# Python-Script stops working when passing through a regex

Tags: python, regex, search

I have a big text file and I am processing it line by line using the for ... in statement:

```
f = open(sys.argv[1])
for line in f:
```

And I pass these lines through some regexes. But my code stops when this long line is being passed through a regex:
This is the line:

```
Mar 25 09:42:22 2011 amavis[30883]: (30883-10) Passed CLEAN, [95.0.85.202] [95.0.85.202] <oyalcin@aaa.com> -> <acanli@aaa.com.tr>,<aeren@aaa.com.tr>,<aergul@aaa.com.tr>,<dalp@aaa.com.tr>,<faks@aaa.com.tr>,<fkonyali@aaa.com.tr>,<hozsoy@aaa.com.tr>,<makcan@aaa.com.tr>,<mengin@aaa.com.tr>,<mervekayabasi@aaa.com.tr>,<muhasebe@aaa.com.tr>,<okkesgol@aaa.com.tr>,<personel@aaa.com.tr>,<skazanci@aaa.com.tr>,<sumur@aaa.com.tr>,<tkececioglu@aaa.com.tr>,<ydemirci@aaa.com.tr>,<abalcin@aaa.com>,<adanisti@aaa.com>,<akaramanli@aaa.com>,<aozsahin@aaa.com>,<benalin@aaa.com>,<cgokburun@aaa.com>,<dkilinc@aaa.com>,<gleblebici@aaa.com>,<hsannan@aaa.com>,<iziyan@aaa.com>,<kcspetrol@aaa.com>,<malakus@aaa.com>,<maltuntas@aaa.com>,<mdelice@aaa.com>,<mguclu@aaa.com>,<mkocyigit@aaa.com>,<mokuducu@aaa.com>,<mtabar@aaa.com>,<m...
```

And this is the regex and the place where the code stops:

```
pattern_clean = re.compile("(\S{3} \d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2} \d{4}).*CLEAN, (LOCAL )?(\[[.\d]+\] )?(\[[.\d]+\] )?<(\S*@(\S*))?> -> (<\S*>,)* Message-ID: <(\S*)>, mail_id: (\S*), Hits: (\S*), queued_as: (\S*), (\S*)")

if pattern_clean.search(line) != None:
```

I have tries this script on a different file it worked okay. It also worked okay with this file too, until this line came. What may be causing this problem?

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Is it possible that the input is pathological to python's regex library? I'm pretty sure python uses a backtacking regex system, so it may be that the input you're giving is throwing it into worst-case behavior. Is the process locked? Taking up lots of cpu?

Comment: No, I didn't get an error message. It just stops there but doesn't quit the script. The cpu usage stays also at max. level

Comment: @Daenyth you may be right. If you look at my regex I have a group like this: <(\S*@(\S*))?> -> (<\S*>,)* And it tries to capture maximum recipient mail addresses. In this case we have a lot of recipient mail addresses.

Comment: Looking at it now, why don't you just trim off the predictable prefix and use the `email` module to extract a list of email addresses from the string? You will never make a regex that will get all legal addresses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to write regular expressions that take a very, very long time to either match or fail. you've written just such a regular expression. Basically any time you see `*` or `+` nested inside another `*` or `+` be very afraid.

I think your problem may be:

```
(<\S*>,)*
```

On it's own, `<\S*>` will match everything up to the next whitespace, then when the full pattern fails to match it will try to shorten the match down, then the outer `*` means it will try lots of different combinations matching 20 emails followed by none, or 19 followed by 1, or 18 followed by 2, or 18 followed by 1 followed by 1. You've got runaway combinations there.

I suggest you try replacing all your `\S` occurences with a pattern that cannot match the terminating character. e.g. `<[^> ]*>` or `[^, ]*,` that may reduce the problem.

Comment: you are right I replaced simply (<\S*>,)* by ([^, ]*,)* and it was not loop over

Comment: (<\S*>,)* I changed this regex to ((<[^>]*>,)*) and now it works fast. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in Python regex, but some general observations

You have plenty of anchors, so greedy quantifiers are ok almost everywhere except in one place.

`(<\S*>,)*` This will not do what you think it will.

In essence, the group will only be executed 0 or 1 time, so it actually does `(<\S*>,)?`.
And, the match will progress like this:

```
<aergul@aaa.com.tr>, ... <dalp@aaa.com.tr>,
^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^
<               \S*                          >,
```

Its not going to capture using an arbitrary number of capture groups.
It is functionally equivalent to (and better written as) this:

`((?:<\S*?>,)+)?`

I've tested `(<\S*>,)*` with the data sample you have provided. It works ok in Perl. But I can only assume your data extends way beyond what you are showing. Just realize your capturing everything up to the next big anchor `>, Message-ID:` in one expression.

It could be re-written as:
`(<\S*?>,)*` which just retains the last `<>,` in the series where parenthesis is only relavent as a non-capture grouping.